# How to center align text in love2D vertically and horizontally?

Tags: lua, love2d

I want to display a text when a specific thing happens in love2d. Everything is working fine except the text displays somewhere away from the center. So i just want to know a way of center aligning text horizontally and vertically. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Horizontal aligning works best with [`love.graphics.printf()`](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.printf). Specify `center` as the alignment.

Alternatively you can use [`font:getWidth(text)`](https://love2d.org/wiki/Font:getWidth) to get the width required in pixels. [`love.graphics.getFont()`](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.getFont) to get the currently active font.

For the height use [`font:getHeight()`](https://love2d.org/wiki/Font:getHeight) or [`font:getBaseLine()`](https://love2d.org/wiki/Font:getBaseline), depending on where the vertical center should be.